# How can I draw a circle in SVG with 2 colors?

Tags: svg

How can I draw a circle in SVG with 2 colors?

I found a tutorial the following example (from [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Weytu)):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="yelgre" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="grecya" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="cyablu" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="blumag" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="magred" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
    <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#redyel)"/>
    <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#yelgre)"/>
    <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#grecya)"/>
    <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cyablu)"/>
    <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#blumag)"/>
    <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#magred)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

But I want to only use 2 colors. I'm trying to make it look like this:

[image: circle image transparent]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually create a circle with two colours with only a single path. Simply set two different `stop-color`. Here, the first `stop-color` is `#00f` (blue), and the secnd `stop-color` is `#f0f` (purple):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="colour" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00f"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f0f"/>   
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,120)">
    <path d="M 0 -100 a 50 50 0 1 0 0.00001 0" stroke="url(#colour)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4yoda5wz/).

Feel free to play around with the `viewBox` and `transform` to suit the desired output location :)

Hope this helps!